# "Cannot recover key" error when generating APK

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal, apk

I'm getting the below error when generating my signed APK:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key0 from store "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/keystore": Cannot recover key

 Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
        at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:315)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
        at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:473)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreDelegator.java:172)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetEntry(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1521)
        at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.getCertificateInfo(KeystoreHelper.java:191)
        ... 32 more
```

I have checked my `executionHistory.bin` file and confirmed both the Keystore password and Key password are correct and are both the same password:

[image]

```
signingConfig.keyAliasÖkey0ösigningConfig.keyPasswordí**mypassword**úsigningConfig.storePasswordí**mypassword**òsigningConfig
```

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to many answers on here, both the **Keystore password** and the **Key password** have to be different:

[image]

My Keystore password was correct, but I had to try different passwords for my Key password (Alias password). And eventually it worked.